# Key preview overlaps key that is pressed

Tags: java, android, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard and there is a problem that when the key is pressed the key preview overlaps the key

```
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#DADBDE"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/background"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview_layout"
android:keyPreviewOffset="@dimen/keyPreviewOffset"
android:keyTextColor="#141518"
android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_layout"
```

Comment: Just to check-  I'm assuming you're using KeyboardView?  I ask because it isn't a requirement to make a keyboard, and most serious keyboards end up not using it in the end due to lack of flexibility (its mainly used to get something up and running quickly if you're really doing something else, like playing with autocorrect algorithms).

Comment: Yes i am using keyboardView class but i cannot figure out that how to show the key preview on the top of the key.